# Is it possible to replicate Kubernetes container network environment with docker compose?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, docker-compose

Kubernetes has a concept of pods where containers can share ports between them. For example within the same pod, a container can access another container (listening on port 80) via `localhost:80`.

However on docker-compose, `localhost` refers to the container itself.

Is there anyway to implement the kubernetes network config on docker?

Essentially I have a kubernetes config that I would like to reuse in a docker-compose config, without having to modify the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have gotten it to work by adding `network_mode: host` to each of the container configs within my docker-compose config.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You run a service and then you can use `network_mode: service:<nameofservice>`

```
version: '3'

services:
  mainnetwork:
    image: alpine
    command: tail -f /dev/null
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    network_mode: service:mainnetwork
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root"
  mysqltest:
    image: mysql
    command: bash -c "sleep 10 && mysql -uroot -proot -h 127.0.0.1 -e 'CREATE DATABASE tarun;'"
    network_mode: service:mainnetwork
```

**Edit-1**

So the `network_mode` can have below possible values

- host
- service:(servicename in same compose file)
- container:(name or id of a external container already running)

In this case i have used `service:mainnetwork`, so the mainnetwork needs to be up.

Also this has been tested on `Docker 17.06 ce`. So I assume you are using a newer version

Comment: Appreciate the answer. Could you possibly add additional info about what this functionality is called? Or any relevant links to docs would also be useful.

Comment: Does this work? If I use the relevent `network_mode` value in my config I get `ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: cannot join network of a non running container:`.

Answer (score -1):

Using [Docker Links](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#connect-using-network-port-mapping) mechanism you can wire together containers and then declared ports will be available through localhost.

Comment: I think this is deprecated.

Comment: Right, but following the link there's an example how to do this with mention of links.